# Click on "Previous" or "Next" button doesn't reflect on listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitems

I have an form with one text field for populating table with only two columns (ID Autoincrement, Name).

I have a listbox which contains records from mentioned table. When I click on one row in listbox, in text field is populated appropriate value for name. But when I iterate through rows with created Next and Previous buttons, then my listbox is not refreshed. In fact, whole time is selected row that I select in start, with mouse click.

I want to refresh selected item in listbox, when I click on Next and Previous buttons.

Actually, when I move through rows with buttons, instead of selecting row with mouse click, then sometimes value in text field isn't same as selected item in listbox.

Comment: Can you paste the code for your buttons please?

Comment: I have a macro related to my `Next` button, and that is `GoToRecord` action with `Next` value for `Record` property. That is all I have.

Comment: Next and Previous worked fine when I click on them, I see it through values in Name field (constantly changed), but in listbox always stay selected same row, regardless of currently active record

Comment: Sorry - I don't mess around with macros. Someone will know how to fix this better than I

Comment: There is no IMPLIED connection between the three objects you mentioned (listbox, textbox, buttons). If you want a certain behavior to happen, you need to implement a solution. Does your form have a recordset? Is your textbox bound to that recordset? What code do you have for when you click on the listbox? Sure, movenext button will 'goto', but you need code to select proper row in listbox (either finding match, or just moving to next row).

Comment: I know there is no IMPLIED connection between those objects, I just need tips how to force listbox to select row which is actual in text field, in fact, that is chosen through navigation buttons. Is that doable via macros?